# center linearlayout verticall android

Tags: android, gravity

Have this code, a scrollview.. a relativelayout and inside it linearlayout..
Problem is at some devices the page takes half the screen size. in other pages it goes to scroll mode. 
i want in cases it takes half screen, to center linearlayout vertically

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>      <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@+id/scrollV"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:fillViewport="true">
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>       <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/linear1"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:baselineAligned="false"
>         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
> ```

Comment: linearlayout is not being centered vertically.. with this above code. do note above linear1 layout there is more code..i just ignored it.

Comment: please dont give answer to centering relativelayout, because there is mising code ...linearlayout will come below other things in xml.

Comment: try with layout_gravity.

Comment: share your whole scrollview code

Comment: way too long of a code for someone to go over it. just assume above linearlayout there is code..and linearlayout comes the last in relativelayout .. i want this linearlayout centered in rest of screen (unless there is scrolling).

Answer (score 1):

okay try this, if it works for you, I've set it centerInParent , so scrollView exactly in center

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

//PUT YOUR STUFF HERE

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```